# Bitmap manipulation throwing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap

I'm trying to write a piece of code to create a black bitmap

```
Bitmap rectangle = new Bitmap(100, 100);
for (int i = 1; i <= rectangle.Width - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; i <= rectangle.Height - 1; j++)
        rectangle.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);
```

But it keeps throwing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: have you tried like this? `i < 100` instead of `i <= rectangle.Width - 1`

Comment: C# uses Zero-based indexing, so your loops should start at 0 instead of 1.
Note that this isn't the reason it's throwing a Exception. I'm just saying that you are skiping the first i and j values.

Comment: I have tried both, i.e. (int i = 0; i < 100; i++), but it didnt solve the problem

Comment: @Trauer I tried indexing from 1, to prevent any possible problems from both sides.

Comment: Last observation: you'll soon find out that Bitmap's SetPixel() method is extremely slow. The Bitmap class is pretty much a wrapper for GDI. Whenever you call SetPixel, it actually calls LockBits(), sets a single pixel and then UnlockBits()... Quite ineficient. Try googling how to use LockBits() and UnlockBits(). You'll see your execution time drop orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap rectangle = new Bitmap(100, 100);
for (int i = 1; i <= rectangle.Width - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; i <= rectangle.Height - 1; j++)
        rectangle.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);
```

The problem is in your second loop's stoping condition:

```
 i <= rectangle.Height - 1
```

should be

```
 j <= rectangle.Height - 1
```

I now this isn't a 'code review' question, but here's a suggestion: avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)
We can do this simply removing `-1` and using `<` instead of `<=`.

```
Bitmap rectangle = new Bitmap(100, 100);
for (int i = 0; i < rectangle.Width; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rectangle.Height; j++)
        rectangle.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);
```

Comment: Not stupid. It's just lack of attention. I do that all the time when I'm tired and trying to code.